# What does symdiff does (in haskell)

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

I am supposed to fill in something for `undefined` to get the program compiled and test it. I don't really know what symdiff here is supposed to do, so I don't know what I can fill in for `undefined`. Can someone give me a hint, what I can insert into `undefined`?

By the way, when I want to compile the code with ghci 7.6.3 I get an error: 
`Could not find module 'Test.SmallCheck.Series'` how can I fix that?

Here is the code:

```
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# language NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Blueprint where

import Test.SmallCheck
import Test.SmallCheck.Series

data N = Z | S N deriving (Show , Eq)

symdiff :: N -> N -> N
symdiff x y = undefined



-- for testing in ghci:  smallCheck 10 spec1


spec1 = \ (x,y) -> symdiff x y == symdiff y x
spec2 = \ (x,y) -> symdiff x (plus x y) == y


plus :: N -> N -> N
plus x y = case x of
    Z -> y
    S x' -> S (plus x' y)

test :: Bool
test = and
   [ null $ failures 10 1000 $ spec1
   , null $ failures 10 1000 $ spec2   
   ]

instance Monad m => Serial m N where series = cons0 Z \/ cons1 S

-- | first f failures from t testcases for property p
failures f t p = take f
               $ filter ( \ x -> not $ p x ) 
               $ take t
               $ do d <- [ 0 .. ] ; list d series
```

thanks, that helped a lot! what about this:

```
symdiff :: N -> N -> N
symdiff x y = case x of
    Z -> y
    S x' -> case y of
        Z -> x
        S y' -> ???
```

Are these lines correct (except the line with ???, I am thinking about it at already)

This works for the last line: 
`S y' -> symdiff x' y'`

Comment: Well done for asking for hints rather than solutions.

Comment: The last lines look fine. Try recursion for the last `???` step.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thanks everybody for helping me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hints are in the smallcheck tests:

```
spec1 = \ (x,y) -> symdiff x y == symdiff y x
spec2 = \ (x,y) -> symdiff x (plus x y) == y
```

This means that `symdiff` needs to satisfy the two equations

```
symdiff x y == symdiff y x  -- shouldn't matter what order (symmetric?)
symdiff x (plus x y) == y   -- if they differ by y, that's the answer (difference)
```

That means that `symdiff` has to find the difference between the two arguments.

You need to think of `Z` as zero and `S x` as the successor of `x`, i.e. `x`+1.

The good news is that there's only two possibilities for `N`, so a maximum of four equations for `symdiff`:

```
symdiff Z Z =
symdiff Z (S y) = 
symdiff (S x) Z = 
symdiff (S x) (S y) =
```

Think about how you would find the difference between
*0 and 0

0 and 1+y

1+x and 0

1+x and 1+y*
to help you.

(You can simplify into fewer cases, but start with these four.)

Have a think about it now, and if that's not enough hinting after a good think, comment.

Comment: More than just +1, this is a really nice answer!